# Ldap: retrieve subgroup from parent group in C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I have security groups in Active Directory account. Security groups have users and also sub groups. I able to get users from Security groups .Here is the code for getting users from security group and I passed "groupname" as parameter.It will return corresponding users belong to group.

```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable(groupName);
        var _with1 = dt.Columns;
        _with1.Add("AccountID", typeof(string));
        _with1.Add("FirstName", typeof(string));
        _with1.Add("LastName", typeof(string));
        _with1.Add("DisplayName", typeof(string));
        _with1.Add("Email", typeof(string));
        _with1.Add("AccountDisabled", typeof(bool));
 using (DirectoryEntry rootEntry = new DirectoryEntry(LDAPPath, LDAPUser, LDAPPassword))
        {
            using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(rootEntry))
            {
            searcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(ObjectClass=Group)(CN={0}))", groupName);
            SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();
            object members = result.GetDirectoryEntry().Invoke("Members", null);
            //<<< Get members

            //<<< loop through members
            foreach (object member in (IEnumerable)members)
            {
                DirectoryEntry currentMember = new DirectoryEntry(member);
                //<<< Get directoryentry for user
                if (currentMember.SchemaClassName.ToLower() == "user")
                {
                    System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection props1 = currentMember.Properties;
                    dt.Rows.Add(props1["sAMAccountName"].Value, props1["givenName"].Value, props1["sn"].Value, props1["displayName"].Value, props1["mail"].Value, Convert.ToBoolean(currentMember.InvokeGet("AccountDisabled")));
                }

            }
```

}
}

But I have no solution to get subgroups that added in Parent security groups.

How can I retrieve the groups from the parent groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works fine for me..

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable(groupName);
        var _with1 = dt.Columns;
        _with1.Add("AccountID", typeof(string));
        _with1.Add("FirstName", typeof(string));
        _with1.Add("LastName", typeof(string));
        _with1.Add("DisplayName", typeof(string));
        _with1.Add("Email", typeof(string));
        _with1.Add("AccountDisabled", typeof(bool));
        _with1.Add("Groups", typeof(string));

        using (DirectoryEntry rootEntry = new DirectoryEntry(LDAPPath, LDAPUser, LDAPPassword))
        {
            using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(rootEntry))
            {
            searcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(ObjectClass=Group)(CN={0}))", groupName);
            SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();
            object members = result.GetDirectoryEntry().Invoke("Members", null);
            //<<< Get members

            //<<< loop through members
            foreach (object member in (IEnumerable)members)
            {
                DirectoryEntry currentMember = new DirectoryEntry(member);
                //<<< Get directoryentry for user
                if (currentMember.SchemaClassName.ToLower() == "user")
                {
                    System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection props1 = currentMember.Properties;
                    dt.Rows.Add(props1["sAMAccountName"].Value, props1["givenName"].Value, props1["sn"].Value, props1["displayName"].Value, props1["mail"].Value, Convert.ToBoolean(currentMember.InvokeGet("AccountDisabled")),"");
                }
                else if (currentMember.SchemaClassName.ToLower() == "group")
                {
                    System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection props1 = currentMember.Properties;
                    //foreach (var group in result.Properties["member"])
                    //{
                        dt.Rows.Add("","","","","",false,props1["name"].Value);
                    //}
                }
            }
   }
```